# How to convert a React Class Component to a Function Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to display an image inside canvas. I did this as a class component but my requirement is to use function component:

```
class Canvas extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const img = this.refs.image;    

    img.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.props.data.w, this.props.data.h);
    }
  }  

  render() {
    const prop = this.props.data;
    return (
      <div data-id={prop.ukey} key={prop.ukey}>
        <canvas data-id={prop.ukey} key={prop.ukey} ref="canvas" width={prop.w} height={prop.h} />
        <img alt="doc-img" ref="image" src={prop.image} className="hidden" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to execute code only in componentDidMount, `useEffect` with empty dependency array is an equivalent of that. Also for refs you would use `useRef` hook

```js
const Canvas = ({data: prop}) => {
    const img = useRef(null);
    const cnv = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
      const canvas = cnv.current;
      const image = img.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

      image.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, prop.w, prop.h);
      }
    }, [])
    return (
      <div data-id={prop.ukey} key={prop.ukey}>
        <canvas data-id={prop.ukey} key={prop.ukey} ref={cnv} width={prop.w} height={prop.h} />
        <img alt="doc-img" ref={img} src={prop.image} className="hidden" />
      </div>
    );
}
```

**P.S. I would highly recommend you to go though the [docs of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and give an attempt at you code in future before asking such question**

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I  am getting error after this

"ReferenceError: Cannot access 'img' before initialization"

on
const img = img.current;

Comment: Yes, As you mentioned in the above solution

Comment: Yes working now. Only need to change cnv to canvas at const ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");